# How to run all threads when getting "the function evaluation requires all threads to run" and the button is missing?

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I'm getting the typical error "The function evaluation requires all threads to run." but I don't have the little button that is usually there to do as it suggests -- i.e. run all the threads, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985564/2704659).

[image]

And yes, I do have this set:

[image]

Comments at the link above indicate this feature may have been removed in VS 2015, but I just used it recently in VS 2017 and today is the first time I've noticed it missing.  I restarted VS, no change.

Answer (score 0):

1.Maybe you can trying watching the property in watch window to check if there has difference.

2.And please check if [workaround from vapcguy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985150/visual-studio-during-debugging-the-function-evaluation-requires-all-threads-to/52193497#52193497) can help. Thanks to him :)

As I found in many issues, adding .ToList() to the end can help fix this issue.