# How to get DBContext again after the Main Thread disposes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, repository-pattern, dbcontext

Net core. I am using EF core, Unit Of Work and Repository pattern. In my code I am releasing my main thread using await Task.Delay(150); Then I am trying to get DB Context but exception says Dbcontext is disposed. So Is there any way I can get DBContext again after the main thread disposes? below few are my code snippets,

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(this.Configuration["AzureSQLConnectionString"]));
services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

Below is my method

```
public Class MyTestBusinessLogic : IMyTestBusinessLogic 
{
    public MyTestBusinessLogic(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(unitOfWork));
        MyTestRepository= UnitOfWork.GetRepository<MyTest>();
    }
    private IDbRepository<MyTest> MyTestRepository{ get; set; }
    public async Task MyMethod()
    {
        await MyTestRepository.GetFirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == Id); // works here 
        await Task.Delay(150);
        // here after my context disposes
        await MyTestRepository.GetFirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == Id); //this wont work and It will throw error inside GetFirstOrDefaultAsync method.
    }
}
```

GetFirstOrDefaultAsync method

```
public class DbRepository<T> : BaseRepository<T>, IDbRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DbContext dbContext;
    private readonly DbSet<T> dbSet;
    public DbRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        this.dbSet = dbContext?.Set<T>();
    }

    public async Task<T> GetFirstOrDefaultAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = this.dbSet; // throws exception saying cannot use disposed object
        foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> include in includes)
        {
            query = query.Include(include);
        }

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            query = orderBy(query);
        }

        return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to fix this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you calling `MyMethod` without `await`?

Comment: Yes Karan I am calling without await

Comment: asp.net creates a DI scope for the lifetime of each request. If you want something to survive the request lifetime, you need a new DI scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am calling without await

This is your problem. So-called "fire and forget" is dangerous on ASP.NET, and is only appropriate when *it doesn't matter whether the code runs or not*. In your case, since you need the code to run, omitting the `await` is inappropriate.

The correct solution is to call `MyMethod` with `await`.

If you absolutely, **must** return early, then the next-best solution is to introduce a reliable queue (e.g., Azure Queue / Amazon SMS) and a background processor (e.g., Azure Function / Amazon Lambda / .NET Core BackgroundService) that processes messages on that queue. Once you have these, when you have a situation where you need to return early and do the work later, then that code will place a message into the queue and then return a result. When the background processor retrieves the message from the queue, it will then do the work.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I understood your point and I am convinced.  So-called "fire and forget" is dangerous on ASP.NET you have mentioned. Can you give me some explanation to this? Thanks

Comment: @MrPerfect: I summarize some of the reasons [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html).

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you are running `MyMethod` without `await`ing it. So while main thread completes execution it will destroy `dbcontext` or any `scoped` objects injected from `DI`.

To fulfill your requirement you can use `IServiceScopeFactory` which is `singleton` object and added by `.net core` framework. Using it you can create `scope` using `serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope()` and create new instance of required `dependencies` using `scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();`.

So in such scenario you can use like below. Please refer comment for understanding. I don't know exact structure of you application so I added `IServiceScopeFactory` to your `MyTest` for example/test. But as per your code you can move it elsewhere I guess in `UnitOfWork`.

```
public Class MyTestBusinessLogic : IMyTestBusinessLogic 
{

    // Add serviceScopeFactory
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory;
    
    // Inject IServiceScopeFactory and assign to class object.
    public MyTestBusinessLogic(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        this.serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        
        // Create scope with IServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope()
        var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
        
        // GetRequiredService unitOfWork
        UnitOfWork = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>();
        // UnitOfWork = unitOfWork ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(unitOfWork));
        
        MyTestRepository= UnitOfWork.GetRepository<MyTest>();
    }
    
    private IDbRepository<MyTest> MyTestRepository{ get; set; }
    
    public async Task MyMethod()
    {
        await MyTestRepository.GetFirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == Id); // works here 
        await Task.Delay(150);
        // here after my context disposes
        await MyTestRepository.GetFirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == Id); //this wont work and It will throw error inside GetFirstOrDefaultAsync method.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Karan but my GetFirstOrDefaultAsync method is DBRepository class not in MyTest. I will update above code accordingly

Comment: IQueryable<T> query = this.dbSet; this line shows The function evaluation requires all threads to run.

Comment: Karan May I know why its showing The function evaluation requires all threads to run?

Comment: I can't understood why it is showing this error but Try creating `UnitOfWork ` & `MyTestRepository` objects inside `MyMethod`.

Comment: Please check this might be the reason https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985150/visual-studio-during-debugging-the-function-evaluation-requires-all-threads-to