# The function evaluation requires all threads to run - debug in VS studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

When debugging with VS studio , i have faced an error that return

> the function evaluation requires all threads to run
> [image]

How should I fix this

I use ef code first on this project

Here is the controller , DbContext and the Models

```
 public class ApplicationController : Controller
{
    ApplicationDbContext _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Brand> brands;
        brands = _context.Brands.ToList();

        return View(brands); 
    }
    }
```

DbContext

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("name=ApplicationDbContext")
    {
    }   

    public virtual DbSet<Brand> Brands { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Brand

```
 public class Brand
{
    [Key]
    public int brand_id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nhập thiếu kìa fen.")]
    public string brandname { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nhập thiếu kìa fen.")]
    public string program { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nhập thiếu kìa fen.")]
    public string currency { get; set; } 
    public string note { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nhập thiếu kìa fen.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime timestart { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nhập thiếu kìa fen.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
    public DateTime timeend { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
}
```

Product

```
 public class Product
{

    [Key]
    public int product_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Brand")]
    public int brand_id { get; set; }
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; private set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nhập thiếu kìa fen.")]
    public string productname { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nhập thiếu kìa fen.")]
    public string condition { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nhập thiếu kìa fen.")]
    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal rebate { get; set; } 
    public string note { get; set; }
}
```

I appreciate every help

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985150/visual-studio-during-debugging-the-function-evaluation-requires-all-threads-to) might help

Comment: Are you trying to expand the results of _context.Brands from the Breakpoint?  If so, no you cannot do that from in the debugger because that is an operation that needs to be sent to the database. Just F10 it and you can inspect the brands entity/proxy list that the operation returns.

Comment: thankyou guys 
i encounter a bug in my project and I thought that because of this problem 
turn out it just a feature in VS studio